# MYSQL REGEXP for text not between parentheses

Tags: mysql, regular-expression

I'm looking to search a large MYSQL table for a string and only return results that aren't between parentheses. If my table looks like this:

```
|  ID   |Data                      |
|   1   |Some search term here     |
|   2   |Search term               |
|   3   |Search term (search term) |
|   4   |(Search term) search term |
|   5   |Here's the (search term)  |
|   6   |Never match this line     |
```

And I want to select the rows where "search term" (case-insensitive) appears, but not in parentheses, how can I write the REGEXP to achieve that?

IDs 1,2,3,4 should return. IDs 5 & 6 shouldn't.

The search term may include letters, numbers and punctuation (though it shouldn't need to support parentheses as they'll never be nested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate regex(or dont get them) so:

```
SELECT id,data FROM table 
WHERE CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,'(',1),'(',''),
REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,')',-1),')','')) 
LIKE '%search term%';
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bfe8/13)